# Wordpress theme translations not being implemented into admin area

Tags: wordpress, localization, custom-post-type, po

I developed a wordpress theme which has a few cusotm post types in it. and i created the `.po` language file and it successfully imported the strings from php files.

The problem is that the translations related to custom post types aren't showing in admin area.
I've tried bot `__()` and `_x()` functions, but no luck.

I appreciate if someone tell me what's the problem here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you load the theme text domain? Example:

```
function so16309230_after_setup_theme(){
    load_theme_textdomain( 'my_theme', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'so16309230_after_setup_theme' );
```

The text domain also needs to be declared in your `style.css` stylesheet header:

`Text Domain: my_theme`